# Place image in PDF from API call in python?

Tags: python, reportlab

Is there any way to place an image to pdf from an url in python? The idea is to generate a pdf with its related image from an API call.
I tried with reportlab and its class ImageReader. After I run this code it crashes the program since io_url is too large.

```
img = 'url_path'
io_url = urllib.request.urlopen(img).read()
image = ImageReader(io_url)
```

EDIT --- Trying with Flask:

```
class PostDogQR(Resource):

def get(self, usermail, dog_name ):

  client = pymongo.MongoClient('credentials')
  filter={'UserMail':usermail,'title':dog_name}

  result = client['dbname']['collection'].find(
    filter=filter
  )
  json_response = json.dumps(list(result), default=json_util.default)
  dog = json.loads(json_response)

  df = pd.DataFrame(dog).to_dict()
  title = df['title'][0]
  breed =df['Breed'][0]
  img_url = 'image_url'
  dog_img = df['DogImg'][0]
  dog_age = df['DogAge'][0]
  dog_desc = df['DogDescription'][0]

  pdf = FPDF(unit='mm')
  pdf.set_font('Arial', 'B', 12)
  pdf.add_page()
  pdf.multi_cell(120.0,4.0,f'Hello! My name is {title}.\nI am a {breed} and I am {dog_age} years old.\n\nThis is my story: {dog_desc}',border=0)
  pdf.image(img_url,150,10,50,60)
  #pdf.output("yourfile.pdf", "F")
  response = make_response(pdf.output(dest='S').encode('latin-1'))
  response.headers.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename= dog_name + '_' + usermail + '.pdf')
  response.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
  return response
```

I get:

```
RuntimeError: FPDF error: Missing or incorrect image file: "here it comes my url image address"
```

Comment: I don't know if you need to use ImageReader, I used the Image object from the platypus library, and simply put the url of an image in the Image function, and it works.

Comment: print the output of "io_url" and paste it in the question, you should ensure that you get a valid URL path

Comment: that's a dynamic image URL and I'm not sure if the Image flowable can use that, it might need to be a static image url with the file extension. There wasn't much written about the image flowable in the documentation so I'm not sure. Can you make the image static or does it need to be from a URL outside of your project?

Comment: the idea is to fetch the image url from my database through my API. So, every time it will be a different url..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the fact that your requirement is to use a dynamic image url...this will work for you:

(Take it that "c" is your canvas variable)

```
import urllib.request

urllib.request.urlretrieve('https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200?sig=1',"image_context.png")
imgSize = 200      
c.drawImage("image_context.png", width=imgSize, x=100, y=100, preserveAspectRatio=True)
```

Flask example:

```
import urllib.request
import io
from reportlab.lib.units import inch, mm, cm
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

def pdf():

    # Create Bytestream buffer
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    
    # Create a canvas
    c = canvas.Canvas(buf, pagesize=A4, bottomup=0)

    urllib.request.urlretrieve('https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200?sig=1',"image_context.png")

    imgSize = 200      
    c.drawImage("image_context.png", width=imgSize, x=100, y=100, preserveAspectRatio=True)

    c.showPage() #show the page
    
    #Save the canvas with the data
    c.save()
    buf.seek(0)

    response = make_response(buf)
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=" + "report" + ".pdf"
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
    return response
```

Comment: it does not raise any error, but the image does not render and the pdf appears in blank. Even with drawInlineImage method does not work while to other people did in other threads.. do not know what to do

Comment: I made a Flask example but haven't tested it. You need to make sure your canvas is rendered, make sure you add a buffer to the canvas like I have in the code, and make sure you do c.showPage() before c.save()

Comment: I have this working in the django framework, I don't mind helping until you get it working in Flask, because it must work. If it doesn't work, you might need another http response header - let me know

Comment: Thanks for your help. I finally tried with another library to render my image (FPDF) and I set up my pdf well, but now I am having some issues making it work with Flask. It basically says that cannot find the image I am trying to attach. (I tested it locally and it works, but I want to make it all online if possible)

Comment: Above you can see the new edit.

Comment: I think maybe you should make a different question as this question was tagged for reportlab. I never used the FPDF library.

Comment: thanks anyway for your help, I will try with reportlab just in case